# How to continuously check internet connection in a multi threading application?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
            String url = settings.Get("URL");
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpRequest.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
            String response = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I am requesting this Api using  `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`.
And every time when I am requesting to Api, I want to check the **internet connection** and if there is internet connection available, it will make a request call. Or else the application will pause until there is no internet connection. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, can you please try to add a bit more information on what you desire

Comment: I am fetching data from sql and requesting an Api for each row of data using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(requestUrl), (object)dr). And before requesting URL, I want to check whether there is internet connection or not. If there is Internet connect then my application with request an URL or else it will pause until there is no internet connection. @TheGeneral

Comment: Why not make the request and if it fails then you don't have an internet connection?

Comment: Also, you're working with a computer so you can't check anything continuously - it's impossible. You can only check continually.